# What is the meaning of the android accelerometer values?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to understand how to use the data from the accelerometer.

When the phone is moved from the horizontal through 180 degress the values of the z-axis go from +g to -g (0 is vertical).

If I move the phone smoothly, and slowly, from the vertical to the left the values go from 0 to +g. However, if I move the phone sharply, to the left, the values first go negative, presumably due to acceleration.

So, as negative values can represent different situations, how can I tell the difference between negative values due to acceleration to the left and negative values due to tilting to the right?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the question. It looks like you are looking for the [TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer values correspond to the acceleration felt on that axis of the phone at any given time. For example, when the phone is in a normal upright position you will find a value of one g in the downward direction. You'll need to utilize all 3 axis in order to accurately track the phones orientation. Since gravity will act on a different axis when the phone is rotated.

Sharp movements are due to additional acceleration caused by the force of your movement. Try printing out the values for each axis twice a second or so while you move the phone around very slowly, and you'll get a feel for what the values mean.